# How can I make my iMac search for a Remote Discs (as though it were a MacBook Air)?

Tags: macos, mac, dvd, compact-disc

How do you enable "DVD or CD Sharing" remote discs on a Mac with a built-in optical drive? I don't mean *offering* discs (which is done via the System Preferences GUI), I mean, *discovering* them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, found this answer [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2009012605560521).

In Terminal, type the following commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser EnableODiskBrowsing -bool true
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser ODSSupported -bool true
```

..then reboot.

Comment: Logging out and back in worked for me FWIW.

Comment: If 'you' 'found' a solution that worked, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Cheers, Josh. i will do so, but SU forces you to wait 48 hrs before you can mark your own answer as "accepted"